# Automorphisms of $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I find the automorphisms of the group $D_8$ ,dihedral group of order $8$?

I've tried just churning them out but that doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have two kinds of elements: rotations and reflections. If $r$ is a $90$-degree rotation and $s$ is a reflection, then the rotations are $1,r,r^2,r^3$ and the reflections are $s,sr,sr^2,sr^3$.

An automorphism $f$ is determined by where it sends the generators $r$ and $s$. Since $r$ has order $4$, the only possibilities are $r\mapsto r$ and $r\mapsto r^3$. Then we need to send $s$ to a reflection since it has order $2$ and is not a power of $r$. We also need 
$$f(srs)=f(r^{-1})=f(r^3)$$

If $f(r)=r$, then $f(s)=s$, $f(s)=sr$, $f(s)=sr^2$, and $f(s)=sr^3$ will all work, which you can verify with a calculation. Similarly we can see that the same is true when $f(r)=r^3$. Thus there are $8$ automorphisms.